# Text-based RPG game using classes

Tags: c++, game, classes, adventure-game

I am studying for a degree in "Bachelor of Engineering in Information and Communication Technologies."  I am currently on vacation, just after we started learning C++ at the end of the semester. I wanted to be ahead of the next semester, so I decided to try to use these classes and to make a text-based game.

I would like to know what I could do better.  Should I remove or add some class functions?  Should I do something differently, maybe not even related to classes?

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "MobClass.h"
#include "Player.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;
player battle(player account);
player calcEXP(player account,classMob monster);
player levelUp(player account);
void death();

int main()
{
    string name;
    int option1;
    cout << "Welcome, please enter your name\n";
    cin >> name;
    string location[4] = {"in a hole","in a cave","in the mauntains","in a castle"};
    player account(name,location[0],1,0);
    cout <<"\nWelcome "<<account.getName() << " you find your self " << account.getArea() << "\nand you are not sure how you ended up here\n";
    while (1)
    {
        Sleep(500);
        cout <<"write 1 to walk forward or 2 to walk left or 3 to walk right\n";
        cin >> option1;
        if (option1 >=1 && option1 <=3)
        {
            Sleep(50*(option1));
            srand(time(NULL));
            if (rand() %3 == option1-1){
                account = battle(account);
            }

        }
        else{
            cout << "\n#@#Error#@# Please enter a number between 1 and 3\n\n";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore();
        }
    }
    return 0;

}




player battle(player account)
{
    string option;
    string location[4] = {"in a hole","in a cave","in the mauntains","in a castle"};
    string monsters[5][3] = {{"worm","lizard","snake"},{"rat","snake","trolls"},{"Dragon","Dragon","Dragon"},{"Evil knight","The mad king","Joffrey Baratheon"}};
    Sleep(20);
    srand(time(NULL));
    int ranM = (rand() % 3); //random monster
    int ranD = (rand() % 5)+1; //random diff
    classMob monster(monsters[account.getLevel()-1][ranM],account.getLevel(),account.getArea(),ranD);
    cout <<"Suddently you meet a "<< monster.getName() <<", be ready for battle" << "\n";
    Sleep(2000);
    do 
    {
        cout << "\n\n\n ######################################\nHP:"<< account.getHealth() << "                                         "<< monster.getName()<<"HP:"<<monster.getHealth()<<" difficulty:"<<monster.getDifficulty() << "\n";
        cout << "Write A for attack or R for retreat" << "\n";
        cin >> option;
        srand(time(NULL));
        if (option == "R" || option == "r")
        {
            if ((rand() % 2) == 1){
                cout << "retreat sucessfull" << "\n";
                monster.setHealth(0);
            }
            else{
                cout << "retreat failed, the monster get a free attack and you lose 5 health\n";
                account.setHealth(account.getHealth()-5);
                option ="A";
            }
        }
        if (option == "A" || option == "a")
        {
            int attack =rand()%(account.getDamage());
            srand(time(NULL));
            int mobAttack = rand()%(monster.getDamage());
            monster.setHealth(monster.getHealth()-attack);
            account.setHealth(account.getHealth()-mobAttack);
            cout << "you attack the monster for " << attack << " damage\n";
            Sleep(500);
            cout << "the monster counter attacks for " << mobAttack << " damage\n";
            Sleep(500);
        }
    } while (monster.getHealth() >0 && account.getHealth() > 0);
    cout << "\n\n\n ######################################\nHP:"<< account.getHealth() << "                                         "<< monster.getName()<<"HP:"<<monster.getHealth()<<" difficulty:"<<monster.getDifficulty() << "\n";
    if (account.getHealth() <= 0)
    {
        death();
        exit(0);
    }
    account = calcEXP(account,monster);
    return account;
}



void death()
{
    cout << "Sorry you failed your epic quest\n";
}

player calcEXP(player account,classMob monster)
{
    cout << "#########\ncalculating EXP\n#########\n";
    Sleep(500);
    account.setEXP(account.getEXP() + monster.getEXP());
    cout << "EXP: " <<account.getEXP() << "/" << account.getEXPReq() << "\n";
    if (account.getEXP() >= account.getEXPReq())
    {
        levelUp(account);
    }
    return account;
}

player levelUp(player account)
{
    account.setLevel(account.getLevel()+1);
    account.setEXPReq();
    account.setMaxHealth();
    account.setHealth(account.getMaxHealth());
    cout << "Level up! you are now level: " << account.getLevel() << "!\n";
    return account;
}
```

**Player.h**

```
#include <string>
class player
{
public:
    player(std::string,std::string,int,int);
    void setName(std::string);
    void setArea(std::string);
    void setLevel(int);
    void setEXP(double);
    void setHealth(double);
    void setMaxHealth();
    void setDamage();
    std::string getName();
    std::string getArea();
    int getLevel();
    double getHealth();
    double getMaxHealth();
    int getDamage();
    int getEXP();
    void setEXP(int);
    int getEXPReq();
    void setEXPReq();
private:
    std::string playerName;
    std::string playerArea;
    int playerLevel;
    double playerHealth;
    double playerMaxHealth;
    int playerDamage;
    int EXP;
    int EXPReq;
};
```

**player.cpp**

```
#include <string>
#include "Player.h"
player::player(std::string name,std::string area,int level = 1,int EXP = 0)
{
    setName(name);
    setArea(area);
    setLevel(level);
    setEXP(EXP);
    setMaxHealth();
    setHealth(playerMaxHealth);
    setDamage();
    setEXPReq();
}

void player::setName(std::string name)
{
    playerName = name;
}
void player::setArea(std::string area)
{
    playerArea = area;
}
void player::setLevel(int level)
{
    playerLevel = level;
}
void player::setHealth(double health)
{
    playerHealth = health;
}
void player::setMaxHealth()
{
    playerMaxHealth = (100 * getLevel());
}
void player::setDamage()
{
    playerDamage = (30 * getLevel());
}

std::string player::getName()
{
    return playerName;
}

std::string player::getArea()
{
    return playerArea;
}

int player::getLevel()
{
    return playerLevel;
}
double player::getHealth()
{
    return playerHealth;
}
double player::getMaxHealth()
{
    return playerMaxHealth;
}
int player::getDamage()
{
    return playerDamage;
}

int player::getEXP()
{
    return EXP;
}
void player::setEXP(int _EXP)
{
    EXP = _EXP;
}
int player::getEXPReq()
{
    return EXPReq;
}
void player::setEXPReq()
{
    EXPReq = 70+((getLevel()*getLevel())*35);
}
```

**mobclass.h**

```
#include <string>

class classMob
{
public:
    classMob(std::string,int,std::string,int); // name,lvl,area,difficulty
    void setName(std::string);
    void setLevel(int);
    void setArea(std::string);
    void setDamage();
    void setHealth(double);
    void setMaxHealth();
    void setDifficulty(int);
    std::string getName();
    int getLevel();
    std::string getArea();
    int getDamage();
    double getHealth();
    double getMaxHealth();
    int getDifficulty();
    int getEXP();
    void setEXP();
private:
    std::string mobName;
    std::string mobArea;
    int mobLevel;
    int mobDamage;
    double mobHealth;
    double mobMaxHealth;
    int mobDifficulty;
    int EXP;
};
```

**mobclass.cpp**

```
#include <string>
#include "MobClass.h"
classMob::classMob(std::string name,int lvl,std::string area,int difficulty)
{
    setName(name);
    setLevel(lvl);
    setArea(area);
    setDifficulty(difficulty);
    setDamage();
    setMaxHealth();
    setHealth(mobMaxHealth);
    setEXP();
}

void classMob::setName(std::string name)
{
    mobName = name;
}

void classMob::setLevel(int level)
{
    mobLevel = level;
}

void classMob::setArea(std::string area)
{
    mobArea = area;
}

void classMob::setDifficulty(int difficulty)
{
    mobDifficulty = difficulty;
}

void classMob::setDamage()
{
    mobDamage = (3 *( getLevel())+((getDifficulty()*getLevel())/2));
}

void classMob::setHealth(double health)
{
    mobHealth = health;
}
void classMob::setMaxHealth()
{
    mobMaxHealth = (15 *(getDifficulty() + getLevel()));
}
std::string classMob::getName()
{
    return mobName;
}

int classMob::getLevel()
{
    return mobLevel;
}
std::string classMob::getArea()
{
    return mobArea;
}
int classMob::getDifficulty()
{
    return mobDifficulty;
}
int classMob::getDamage()
{
    return mobDamage;
}
double classMob::getHealth()
{
    return mobHealth;
}
double classMob::getMaxHealth()
{
    return mobMaxHealth;
}

int classMob::getEXP()
{
    return EXP;
}

void classMob::setEXP()
{
    EXP = (getLevel() * 35);
}
```

Comment: Without commenting the code (yet), the first paragraph would read more easily as "I am studying for a degree of "Bachelor of Engineering in Information and Communication Technologies", currently on vacation, just after we started learning C++ at the end of the semester. I wanted to be ahead of the next semester so I decided to try to use these classes and to made a text based game." (Yet SE does not let me perform this edit?)

Comment: Ok, yea it sounds better / properly is more correct that way. Changed it! :)

Comment: Initializing srand(): http://stackoverflow.com/a/322995/14065

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- Try not to get in the habit of using `using namespace std`.  Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) for more information.
- For clarity, have your `#include`s organized.  Read [this blog post](http://blog.knatten.org/2010/07/01/the-order-of-include-directives-matter/) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762568/c-c-include-file-order-best-practices) for more information.
- Add a newline between each section of code.  For instance, separate all user input and loops.  For variables, it's best to initialize them late as late as possible in case the function needs to terminate prematurely.  Again, keep them with the corresponding code.
- `mobclass.h` already includes `<string>`, so you don't need to include it again in the .cpp file.
- You have a lot of accessors and mutators.  Since these are short one-line implementations, you can define them in the header like this:

  ```
  void setEXP() {EXP = (getlevel() * 35;}
  int getEXP() const {return EXP;}
  ```

  As such, you will no longer need to implement these in the .cpp file.  When they're in the header, they'll automatically be `inline`.  It should also make it easier if you ever need to implement newer functions.  In the header, you could also keep the accessors and mutators together for clarity.
- I like what @Kaivo Anastetiks said about `classMob`'s constructor, but I would like to add on that a bit.  You have a few options for this:

  1. keep it in the .cpp file (with those changes)
  2. put it in the header (with the `classMob::` part removed)
  3. put it under the class declaration in the same file
- It's better to use `getline()` instead of `cin` for getting an `std::string` value from the user:

  ```
  getline(std::cin, name);
  ```
- `srand()` should ONLY be called ONCE in the program, preferably at the top of `main()`.  If you keep it as is, `rand()` will be "not-so-random" because the seed will keep resetting to 0.
- That really long output line in `battle()`'s do-while loop could be wrapped so that it doesn't extend out that far.
- For `death()`: there's no need to have a function *just* output a message.  Either have it do something else relevant, or just remove it.
- For the player's death (in general): I would prefer the function to fall back to `main()` instead of explicitly exiting.  This is because:

  1. it's clearer to let `main()` terminate the program whenever possible
  2. it could be hard to tell where the player's death is determined

  You would then need to change `main()`'s loop to handle this.  You could even have `battle()` return a `bool` to indicate the battle outcome (the player has won or has lost).  Try this at the end:

  ```
  account = calcEXP(account, monster);

  if (account.getHealth() <= 0)
      return false;

  return true;
  ```

  You could even create a `bool` member function for determining if the player's health was depleted:

  ```
  bool healthDepleted() const {return playerHealth <= 0;}
  ```
- If you're just mutating data members in `calcEXP()` and `levelUp()`, they don't need to return anything.  Just make those functions `void`.
- Your "saving" problem is due to your functions receiving the objects *by value*.  It should be received *by reference* instead.  You were only passing in a copy and modifying it, only to have those changes discarded each time those functions ended.  This change will allow you to modify the original objects:

  ```
  bool battle(player &account);
  void calcEXP(player &account, classMob &monster);
  ```
- After looking at `mobClass`'s definition, it appears that you may not need those mutators.  You should consider a `mobClass` instance as an *individual* monster, just as a `player` is just *one* player.  As such, you just need to construct each `mobClass` once with the default stats.  The accessors are still okay.
- Once again, I forgot about this: create a `Game` class.  Since the human player doesn't need to know how the game's internal mechanisms work, you would no longer need those extra functions in the driver.  Instead, `main()` will create a `Game` and the class will handle the rest.  Here's (roughly) what `main()` could look like:

  ```
  int main()
  {
      std::srand(std::time(NULL));

      Game game;
      game.play();
  }
  ```

  That may be *too* little for `main()`, but the idea is that `Game` will handle everything.  Every function in `Game`, except for `play()`, should be `private`.  `Game` should contain a `player` as a data member and instantiated in `Game`'s constructor.  If you end up implementing your map idea (or anything similar), that would be instantiated in the constructor as well.  You may still keep those extra driver functions, but they should be called in `play()` instead.

  As for `classMob`, you could create an `std::vector` of objects (you cannot predict how many monsters will "spawn" before the player dies).  New monsters would be added and, when killed by the player, removed.  If you maintain a counter, you could even track the number of monsters killed before defeat.

Comment: "[K]eep all variable initializations at the top of the function" -- I disagree. Variables should be declared as late as possible. This avoids unnecessary instantiation in case of exceptions or `return`s, and keeps them closer to the relevant context.

Comment: Regarding `#include` order: The recommended order is **1.** Include yourself (i.e. corresponding `.hpp` file from a `.cpp` file). **2.** Include other headers you have created yourself. **3a.** Include other `""`-style headers. **3b.** Include non-std-lib `<>`-headers. **4.** Include standard library headers. Each section should be in alphabetical order. See [this blog post](http://blog.knatten.org/2010/07/01/the-order-of-include-directives-matter/) for an explanation, or [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762568/c-c-include-file-order-best-practices).

Comment: What do you mean by "It should also make it easier if you ever need to implement longer functions"? Then you would have to move them back to the implementation file. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I meant for new functions (not the same assessors and mutators).  I'll clarify that.

Comment: I'll clarify the variable thing as well.  You are right, but I was going back to the separation thing.

Comment: The rest looks good. I think you mean "`srand()` should only be **called** once", by the way.

Comment: Oh alright, this line: void setEXP() const {EXP = (getlevel() * 35}; was I just told wouldnt be that smart to do(because it has more then one operation), also changed it to be inline instead(as requested below as it seems to be smarter :) ).I was wondering why i got so unrandom mobs, but it works alot better after i removed those srand() so now its only in main. The reason to i have return values on calcEXP and levelUp() is to "save the information(I tried earlier to have it as a void function but it wouldnt save the new XP, it is the same for the function battle, as it just returns account.

Comment: Great feedback though, alot to work on. I got one question though. In my code i have this line "if (option1 >=1 && option1 <=3)" 
but if i type something like the charter A it obviously gives an error to the cin function. If this happends(if it is not between 1 and 3) then it clears the cin function but this does not seem to work as it doesnt wait on an input from the user but just keep spamming :"write 1 to walk forward or 2 to walk left or 3 to walk right\n" Can you tell me why this is ?

Comment: I added an extra note about `inline` in the header.  As for the account, it should be "saved" into the program as long as you're properly updating the data members AND using the same objects.  That's just a part of using classes.

Comment: That is because the `std::cin` is expecting an `int`, but receives a `char` instead.  `std::cin` is not safe for dealing with such input because it is not designed to handle exceptions.  You would then need to call `std::cin.ignore()` each time to disregard that `char` for the next input.  Either way, it just puts unnecessary data into the stream.

Comment: Oh I will try with getline() instead and see how that works. also you write void setEXP() const {EXP = (getlevel() * 35;} but should there be a const there ? as the function does change a value?

Comment: Oh yes, you're right.  I thought through this too quickly.  `Const` is not for mutators.

Comment: Also does it mean that i can call the function battle with no argument? as it should know it out from the object or should i still have it as a parameter? oh yea I have seen the button but i just try to get as much input as possible, will choose the best answer tomorrow(right now yours is the best yea :) )

Comment: It would still need the `player` object as an argument.  Speaking of which, I found your "saving" problem.  I'll update this answer.

Comment: Ah yea forgot it only made a copy, thanks! I removed the death function and made battle to bool now and made it like this in main instead
"if (battle(account) == true)
{
    std::cout<<"You died\n";
    return 0;}"

Comment: Just to nit-pick a bit: I'd rename the `player` object as "player1" or something like that.  The object is already sort of an "account" for the player, so it doesn't need to be named like that.

Comment: Oh one question not related that much to the code, but why is it that the command Sleep has to start with a capital S, I thought as standard programming you stated fuctions and variables with a lower case first letter? There might not be a reason I am just curious

Comment: Oh when you say player you mean account don't you ? as it is the class with the name player? 

Because yes it does make more sence to call it account1

Comment: The name `player` for the `class` describes the properties of an _instance_ of said class, which is your object.  In this game, you only have one player.  Yes, you could still say `account1`, but the naming really is up to you.  I'm just trying to relate this to an actual video game (like Zelda). :-)

Comment: That's just how it's defined in the STL under `Windows`.  Not everything in there is written under common naming conventions (at least the way it's taught to us), but I'm sure there are reasons for that.  With the `string` class, for instance, I assume it's lowercase because it's written as a user-defined data type (native data types, such as `int`, are always lowercase).

Comment: I was thinking about maybe adding a map as the next thing to the game maybe as a 3 dimensional array(or maybe 4: 1th for the map area,2nd for the x,3th for y, and 4th for the name of the map) but would this be the smartest way? i was thinking about maybe adding something to the class player or maybe a whole new class for the map but not sure if that would be "smart" ?
Thanks for all your help up till now so I gave you the accepted answer, hope you will keep helping me a bit more :)

Comment: I'm honestly not sure how to go about this myself.  If you don't get any more answer here, you can attempt this and then post another question if you want it reviewed (as long as you're not reporting on errors).  I will say this in general: the STL is your friend.  If you can implement this without using C-style arrays, more power to you.  Moreover, I'll add more to this answer if I can.  Again, you're welcome to start another post after you've made all of your changes and/or want feedback for something more specific.

Answer (score 8):

Your classes are designed badly:

```
class player
{
public:
    player(std::string,std::string,int,int);
    void setName(std::string);
    void setArea(std::string);
    void setLevel(int);
    void setEXP(double);
    void setHealth(double);
    void setMaxHealth();
    void setDamage();
    std::string getName();
    std::string getArea();
    int getLevel();
    double getHealth();
    double getMaxHealth();
    int getDamage();
    int getEXP();
    void setEXP(int);
    int getEXPReq();
    void setEXPReq();
private:
    std::string playerName;
    std::string playerArea;
    int playerLevel;
    double playerHealth;
    double playerMaxHealth;
    int playerDamage;
    int EXP;
    int EXPReq;
};
```

You are exposing all the internal members (they just happen to be behind shallow get/set functions). But you are tightly coupling your class to the actual types you use for storage. This tight coupling makes your code very brittle; any change is going to ripple through your code requiring any code that uses your class to also change.

Your class methods should be "VERBS" that describe actions that happen on your obeject (thus not exposing the internal types).

Example Leveling up:
The only reason you have a bunch of these getters is so that an external function can get update then update the value.

```
player levelUp(player account)
{
    account.setLevel(account.getLevel()+1);
    account.setEXPReq();
    account.setMaxHealth();
    account.setHealth(account.getMaxHealth());
    cout << "Level up! you are now level: " << account.getLevel() << "!\n";
    return account;
}
```

The problem here is that you loose control of leveling up. With this technique anybody can write an alternative way of leveling up. Then if things change you need to find and modify all the techniques when you change how leveling up is done.

This should all be part of the player class that way leveling up is controlled as part of the player. It is done in one place (and only one place):

```
player Player::levelUp()
{
    playerLevel++;
    EXPReq          = 70  + (playerLevel * playerLevel) * 35;
    playerMaxHealth = 100 * playerLevel;
    playerHealth    = playerMaxHealth;

    cout << "Level up! you are now level: " << account.getLevel() << "!\n";
}
```

You can basically remove all the getter/setter methods and put in methods that actual manipulate the object.

#### Edit Based on Comment:

> hm I am getting one problem though, so in the function calcEXP I am using monster.getEXP(); and i know that in the function battle I use some of the get functions to get information about the classMob class. How can i acess this without the use of get functions ?

Couple of ways. But I think the simplest is to make a common base class that handles this stuff:

```
 class LifeForm
 {
      // Traits that are common to both players and monsters.
      int EXP;
      int EXPReq;

           void levelUp() {}
       public:
           void hasKilled(LifeForm const& deadLifeForm)
           {
                  // Absorb the experience of the foe.
                  EXP += deadLifeForm.EXP;

                  if (EXP >= EXPReq)
                  {
                      levelUp();
                  }
           }
           
      
 };

 class Person: public LifeForm
 {
 };

 class Monster: public LifeForm
 {
 };
```

The `LifeForm` class understands the concept of experience (maybe other stuff) and handles the interaction between two lifeforms. Since an object has access to the private members of other objects of the same class it works fine.

Comment: Ah I see, I will start changing this. Thanks!

Comment: ehm I am getting one problem though, so in the function calcEXP I am using monster.getEXP(); and i know that in the function battle I use some of the get functions to get information about the classMob class. How can i acess this without the use of get functions ?

Comment: @Sumsar1812: See update

Comment: @LokiAstari: Thank you for posting this update before I had the slightest idea of mentioning `friend`.  I really need to learn how to use inheritance in my own code.

Comment: @Jamal: friend is another valid technique.

Comment: @LokiAstari: I keep hearing things about `friend` like 1.) it's bad for encapsulation and 2.) it should only be used when absolutely necessary.  I'm still using it in my code, but it feels... too easy to use.  What are the pros/cons of inheritance and `friend`?  You may just point me to a good post.

Comment: @Jamal: If used incorrectly any functionality is bad. But used correctly `friend` increases (ie is good for) encapsulation (at the cost of tight coupling). See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/99595/12917

Comment: @LokiAstari: I may eventually post a snippet of another program pertaining to this very issue.  It uses a Game `class`, and I've never had such a `class` reviewed before.

Comment: I must be honest this is very confusing. so is this called "inheritance " ? If so,it might take some time before i fully understand it(as I have never worked with inheritance before ) and come back with feedback(properly first tomorrow)

Comment: Hmm now it might just be me not understanding this right but shouldn't "void hasKilled(LifeForm const& deadLifeForm)" not be with the monster class instead of the LifeForm class? as another thing to make it a bit easier for my self I changed the EXP names to be playerEXP and PlayerEXPReq and mobEXP

Comment: @Sumsar1812: Don't monsters gain experience from killing players?

Comment: @Sumsar1812: Yes this is inheritance.

Comment: @Sumsar1812: Its not the only way of doing it just a suggestion of one way. friendship would be another.

Comment: @LokiAstari No monsters does not get experience from killing players ;) And no I kinda want to use this methode as I have to learn to use it one way or another

Answer (score 7):

First off, decide whether, and to what degree, you want object orientedness.

If you want to keep the current design, you may want to use structs rather than classes.  At the moment this isn't very object-oriented at all, and getting rid of the need for getters and setters for everyfreakingthing would reduce the amount of code by like 2/3.  Making something private and adding a getter and setter that just blindly set the variable...that's not encapsulation.  That's busywork.  You're not really protecting anything, you end up having to declare and define the getter/setter, and you turn `player.health -= 10;` into `player.setHealth(player.getHealth() - 10);`, which is harder to read.  :P

If you want to be more object-oriented about all this, the first thing to do is let the classes take more responsibility for their own internal state.  As many as possible of the actions that involve modifying player attributes, should be in the `player` class.  Same with monster attributes and `classMob`, of course.

Consider your current fight logic:

```
player battle(player account) {
    ...
    do {
        ...
        if (option == "A" || option == "a")
        {
            int attack =rand()%(account.getDamage());
            srand(time(NULL));
            int mobAttack = rand()%(monster.getDamage());
            monster.setHealth(monster.getHealth()-attack);
            account.setHealth(account.getHealth()-mobAttack);
            cout << "you attack the monster for " << attack << " damage\n";
            Sleep(500);
            cout << "the monster counter attacks for " << mobAttack << " damage\n";
            Sleep(500);
        }
    } while (monster.getHealth() >0 && account.getHealth() > 0);

    ...

    if (account.getHealth() <= 0)
    {
        death();
        exit(0);
    }

    ...

    return account;
}
```

A huge amount of this is stuff that `classMob` and `player` could be handling.  You could easily have something like

```
int player::attack(classMob& mob) {
    int attack = rand() % damage;
    mob.takeDamage(attack);
    return attack;
}

void player::takeDamage(int damage) {
    health -= damage;
    if (health < 0) health = 0;
}

bool player::isAlive() { return health > 0; }



int classMob::attack(player& p) {
    int attack = rand() % damage;
    p.takeDamage(attack);
    return attack;
}

void classMob::takeDamage(int damage) {
    health -= damage;
    if (health < 0) { health = 0; }
}

bool classMob::isAlive() { return health > 0; }
```

Now your player and mob can attack each other, and the above main-manages-the-attack code turns into

```
player battle(player account) {
    ...
    do {
        ...
        if (option == "A" || option == "a")
        {
            int attack = account.attack(monster);
            cout << "you attack the monster for " << attack << " damage\n";
            Sleep(500);

            int mobAttack = monster.attack(account);
            cout << "the monster counter attacks for " << mobAttack << " damage\n";
            Sleep(500);
        }
    } while (monster.isAlive() && account.isAlive());

    ... show status lines again ...

    if ( !account.isAlive() )
    {
        death();
        exit(0);
    }

    ...
}
```

(By the way, if we take a look, we will see that monsters and players attack each other in the same way.  In fact, they share a whole lot of the same attributes.   It's starting to look like `classMob` and `player` should have a common ancestor, at least.)

It might not look that much better, and as of yet, it's still not great.  But you gain a few things by giving players and mobs some autonomy:

- Clarity.  When you want a mob to attack, you don't have to set the player's health to some lower amount determined by the mob's damage.  You just *tell it to attack*.  The resulting code is much more self-descriptive, which makes it much easier to follow.
- Scalability.  Eventually, you're going to want to add features -- like, say, health potions.  Or spiffy weapons that increase the damage dealt.  Or debuffs that occasionally make you or the mob miss a turn.  If you leave the classes dumb and keep `main` doing all the manipulation, there will be a point where it's too painful to add more stuff.

  With OOP done right, on the other hand, you get stuff done by telling an object to do something -- which often causes it to give orders to another object, which causes that other object to send messages to a bunch of others, and so on.  The work's spread out, much more granular, and thanks to polymorphism, hot-swappable -- you can change the program's behavior on the fly by simply replacing some object with a compatible one that does things the way you want it to.

---

As far as the game goes, you might want to change how fleeing works.  Right now, if i run away from a fight, the monster dies?  And i get as much EXP as if i had stayed and killed it?  Something's not right about that.

Answer (score 3):

For the classes, the get functions could have a const keyword in their prototype since they aren't supposed to change any value. That will just make it impossible for them to do so and will make it possible to use them in other const functions.

In the .h

```
int getDamage() const;
```

In the .cpp

```
int player::getDamage() const {...}
```

Also, the get and maybe even set functions could be declared inline, placed at the end of the .h file, to avoid function calls. Inline functions are not compiled as functions. Instead, the body of the function kind of replaces the function call when compiled, similar to Macros. This way, on runtime, there's no actual function call. It's perfect when returning values.

In the class declaration:

```
class player
{
public:
    int getDamage() const;
}
```

In the .h after the class declaration:

```
inline int player::getDamage() const {return damage;}
```

For the constructor, instead of calling the set functions, you could add the values before the function body:

```
classMob::classMob(std::string name,int lvl,std::string area,int difficulty)
: mobName(name), mobLevel(lvl), mobArea(area), mobDifficulty(difficulty)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Ok I changed the get functions to have a const keyword in their prototype. I changed the get and set functions to be declared inline, witch results in I can clear almost all of my player.cpp file and my Mobclass.cpp file. I just want to be sure I am doing it the right way: 
void setEXP(){EXP = (getLevel() * 35);}; 
and
const int getLevel(){return mobLevel;};
So was it like that you ment?
Finaly I changed the constructors and I didnt know you could do that, but i didn't change all of it as i still needed some of the functions(setDamage,setMaxHealth,etc) as those doesnt take a parameter right?

Comment: also thank you so much for the feedback! :)

Comment: The const keyword has to go at the end of the prototype to declare a function as const, otherwise you declare that the return type will be a const. As for the inline, it's like a function with the inline keyword at the beginning of the prototype, but instead of being placed in the .cpp, it's placed in the .h, outside of the class scope. Finally, I said you could almost even put the set functions inline because I think some of them have only a single operation. If you have getLevel() * 35, you have more than one operation in the line.